# How to compile fragment shader ahead of time?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

The documentation for `SKShader` says:

> Compiling a shader and the uniform data associated with it can be
> expensive. Because of this, you should initialize shader objects when
> your game launches, not while the game is running.

From that I assumed that the shader would compile when it is initialized, but that's not the case (probably a bug?); it seems to compile the moment it makes its first *appearance*, so I get a short app-wide lag the first time this happens, along with a shader compilation succeeded message in the console.

I can fix this by adding a zero size node to the scene, and cycling through any needed shaders .

```
let node = SKSpriteNode()
node.shader = someShader
scene.addChild(node)
```

Kind of hack...is there a better way to compile a shader ahead of time?

Comment: Maybe store the shaders on a static let property?

Comment: Indeed the shader does not compile on initialization, rather when it makes its first appearance. Have you found a proper solution or the hack is still the only option? Similar unanswered question is on Apple Dev Forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690915